# Is there a way to create a TFS/VSTS label whenever a project is published?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, pubxml

IS there a simple method or extension to create TFS/VSTS labels whenever a web application project is successfully published?

I've looked into creating a task step to execute the TF command after publishing, but it seems a clumsy way to do it when VS2019 already has methods to add labels.

Comment: Do you mean a **TFVC** label?

Comment: @DanielMann YEs. As far as I'm aware it's the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid there is not a simple method or extension that can do this in VS2019.

But you can try publishing your web application in the pipeline, which you can configure to label your sources automatically after publishing the application.

See below screenshot:

On the **Edit page** of the pipeline-->go to **Get sources** section-->select On success/Always to **Label sources**-->Specify a Label format

[image]

Comment: I'm using VS2019 and explicitly publishing the web app, not using the web interface and/or CI. There is no pipeline.